# Displaying Maths equation in android

Tags: java, android, latex, mathjax, tex

I want to display  mathematical equations in android and  i found this https://github.com/kexanie/MathView which is working perfectly fine but in this code from where can i get the string tex for an equation. I tried converting an equation into latex format using word 16 but when i replace my converted latex string into the original string (String tex in the MainActivity) , instead of the equation getting displayed the latex string gets displayed as it is.

The First MainActivity code is displaying the equation perfectly

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MathView formula_two;
    String tex = "This come from string. You can insert inline formula:" +
            " \\(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\\) " +
            "or displayed formula: $$\\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \\frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        formula_two = (MathView) findViewById(R.id.formula_two);

        formula_two.setText(tex);
    }
}
```

this is MainActivity in which i replaced the tex string with my string

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MathView formula_two;
    String tex = "\\begin{document}\n" +
            "\n" +
            "%\\selectlanguage{english} %%% remove comment delimiter ('%') and select language if required\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\\noindent ${\\left(x+a\\right)}^n=\\int^n_{k=0}{\\left(\\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{n}{k}\\right)x^ka^{n-k}}$  this is a test to check latex format  ${\\left(1+x\\right)}^n=1+\\frac{nx}{1!}+\\frac{n\\left(n-1\\right)x^2}{2!}+\\dots $\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\\noindent \n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\\end{document}";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        formula_two = (MathView) findViewById(R.id.formula_two);

        formula_two.setText(tex);
    }
}
```

> For sure i am doing something wrong in converting a mathematical
>   equation into tex format. how can convert it perfectly i tried
>   searching for a good tutorial but couldnt find any. Any help would be
>   appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MathJax does not process complete LaTeX documents, only mathematical expressions.  So you will not be able to render the `tex` variable that you have defined.  In particular, MathJax thinks anything between `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}` is a math expression, so the `\begin{document}...\end{document}` would be treated as math.  The `\noindent` macros would be unrecognized (only math-mode macros are implemented), and the extra dollar signs would be rendered as literal dollar signs.

Also, note that single dollar-sign delimiters are not enabled in MathJax's default configurations, so you would need to enable them explicitly if you want them to act as math delimiters.  See the [MathJax Documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/tex2jax.html) for more details.